# In Python/KivyMD. MDDialog with check boxes where "CONFIRM" button doesn't work if one of check boxes are checked

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I made a game with `python 3.9.5`, `kivy 2.0.0rc4` and `kivymd 0.104.2`. I made MDDialog. In it there are check boxes. If none of them is checked, I want to disable "confirm" button. And if one of them is checked I want to enable "confirm" button. I've managed to disable when none of them aren't checked, but if I check one of them, button is still disabled. Here's my `python` code:

```
class ItemConfirm(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    divider = None
    dialog = None

    def show_confirmation_dialog(self, *args):

        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            title="Score Limit",
            type="confirmation",
            auto_dismiss=False,
            items=[
                ItemConfirm(text="30"),
                ItemConfirm(text="40"),
                ItemConfirm(text="50"),
                ItemConfirm(text="60"),
            ],
            buttons=[
                MDFlatButton(
                    text="CONFIRM", text_color=(1, 0, 0, 1), on_release=self.score_limit, disabled=True if self.ids.check.active == False else False
                ),
            ]
        )
        self.dialog.open()

    def score_limit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.dialog.dismiss()
```

And here's my `kivy` code:

```
<ItemConfirm>

    CheckboxLeftWidget:
        id: check
        group: "check"
```

Comment: And also I wanna know if I can give an id to a button in MDDialog. If I can, I wanna know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your `confirm` Button enabled/disabled by defining a `BooleanProperty` that reflects if any Checkbox is active. The easiest way to do this is by taking advantage of the automatic bindings created by the kivy lang. In order to do this, I had to basically re-write your code. I apologize for the re-write, but here is a revision of your code that does what you want:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox

kv = '''
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<ItemConfirm>
    divider: None
    CheckboxRightWidget:
        id: check
        score: root.text  # makes the score text available from the Checkbox
        group: "check"
        on_active: app.check_active(self.group)  # update app.active
        
<ConfirmButton@MDFlatButton>:
    text: 'CONFIRM'
    disabled: not app.active  #  disabled when app.active is False
    on_release: app.score_limit()
    
<ConfirmDialog>:
    title: "Score Limit"
    type: "confirmation"
    auto_dismiss: False
    items: [ Factory.ItemConfirm(text="30"), Factory.ItemConfirm(text="40"), Factory.ItemConfirm(text="50"), Factory.ItemConfirm(text="60") ]
    buttons: [ Factory.ConfirmButton() ]
'''


class ItemConfirm(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    pass


class ConfirmDialog(MDDialog):
    pass


class TestApp(MDApp):
    active = BooleanProperty(False)  # keeps track if any Checkbox is active

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Button(text='Do It', on_release=self.show_confirmation_dialog)

    def show_confirmation_dialog(self, *args):
        self.dialog = ConfirmDialog()
        self.dialog.open()

    def score_limit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('score limit:', self.check_active('check'))
        self.dialog.dismiss()
        self.dialog = None  # required to eliminate current group of Checkboxes
        self.active = False

    def check_active(self, group):  # update app.active and return current score limit (or None)
        for cb in MDCheckbox.get_widgets(group):
            if cb.active:
                self.active = True
                return cb.score
        self.active = False
        return None


TestApp().run()
```

Because of the way that `MDDialog` must be built (`buttons` must be a list of  `Button` objects), I do not know of any way to assign an `id` to those `Buttons`.

Comment: I think it will work but how do I open MDDialog. With this new code, I can't figure it out. I have a button that sends me to another class and I want it to appear on that next class(Thanks for trying to help me btw)

Comment: And can you write the kivy code different way. It doesn't work for me because I have separated kivy and python codes. this "#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory" and "<ConfirmButton@MDFlatButton>:" does not work for me

Comment: You open the `MDDialog` by calling the `show_confirmation_dialog()` method. Separate files for `.kv` and `.py` is not a problem, just copy the `kv` string into your `.kv` file.

Comment: I did every thing. It shows MDDialog with button and title, but there is nothing in it